# Skip Stages in Jenkins shared library based on repository

Tags: jenkins, groovy, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

I have a common Jenkins shared library for all the repositories as below.

**vars/_publish.groovy**

```
    pipeline {
        environment {
            abc= credentials(’abc')
            def= credentials(‘def’)
 
        }
        stages {
            stage('Build') {
                steps{
                    sh ‘docker build'
                }
            }
           stage('Unit-test') {
                steps{
                    sh ‘mvn test'
                }
            }
```

**jenkinsfile**

```
@Library('my-shared-library@branch') _

_publish() {
}
```

I have 10 Repository each has its own Jenkinsfile as shown above which refers to the jenkins shared library(**vars/_publish.groovy**). I have a condition here that I need to Pass. For few repository I want to skip the Unit test and just execute the build stage. For rest other repository I want both the stages. Is there anyone I can skip the particular stage based on the repository or repository name

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible you can use when expression like this

```
pipeline {
  agent any 
  stages {
    stage('Test') {
     when { expression { return repositoryName.contains('dev') } } <---------Add put your repository name 'dev' so whenever the repository names is ''dev' then execute this stage
      steps {
        script {
        
        }
      }
   }
  }
}

def repositoryName() {
  def repositoryName = ['dev', 'test'] <----Add here the 10 repo name
  return repositoryName 
}
```

Here in my case repo names are dev and test so you can add yours accondigly

Comment: what should I replace **'name'** and **'another repository name'** to? There are 10 repository sharing that same file so do I need to specify each repo name?

Comment: yes. you have to specify 10 repo names. or maybe get reponames dyanamically somehow and use that in when condition

Comment: We keep adding new services/ repositories adding the names will make the jenkins-shared-library very big and complex. I derive the name of my repository  in environment block as variable "Name" dynamically. But I am not sure how do i get other repo name and set in when condition.

Comment: What should I replace **YourRepositoryName**, **name**, **another repository name** to?

Comment: you no need to hardcode the repo name in the shared library. Instead you can enable your shared library to accept parameters from Repos Jenkinsfile and decide what to do. I have added an example - Please take a look

Answer (score 0):

I would decorate my shared library and Jenkinsfile like this to achieve your scenario.

**vars/_publish.groovy**

```
def call(body={}) {
    def pipelineParams = [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = pipelineParams
    body()
    pipeline {
        agent any;
        stages {
            stage('build') {
                steps {
                    echo "BUILD"
                }
            }
            stage('unitest') {
                when {
                    anyOf {
                        equals expected: true, actual: pipelineParams.isEmpty();
                        equals expected: false, actual: pipelineParams.skipUnitest
                    }  
                }
                steps {
                    echo "UNITEST"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am enabling my shared library to accept parameter from Jenkinsfile and with `when{}` DSL deciding whether to skip unitest stage or not

**Jenkinsfile**

If your Jenkins file from the repo has below details, will skip the unitest stage

```
@Library('jenkins-shared-library')_
_publish(){
    skipUnitest = true
}
```

below both scenario will run the unitest stage

```
@Library('jenkins-shared-library')_
_publish(){
    skipUnitest = false
}
```

and

```
@Library('jenkins-shared-library')_
_publish(){
}
```